# Replicate pandas dataframe for each instance of field in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. Input_df1 is a concatenation of files with a 'filename' column, 'unitid', and many columns of data which I simplify as 'data' for this example. Input_df2 has 'filename' column in addition to 'group'. I'm trying to replicate the data in input_df1 per filename for each instance of filename in input_df2 and add a group column in the output dataframe showing which group it belongs to.

```
import pandas as pd

input_df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'filename' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'unitid'   : [ 1,   2,   3,   4 ],
    'data'     : [11,  12,  13,  14 ]
})

input_df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'filename' : ['A',  'B',  'C',  'C',  'A' ],
    'group'    : ['g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4', 'g5']
})

output_df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'filename' : [ 'A',  'A',  'A',  'A',  'B',  'C',  'C',  'A',  'A',  'A',  'A'],
    'unitid'   : [   1,    2,    1,    2,    3,    4,    4,    1,    2,    1,    2],
    'data'     : [  11,   12,   11,   12,   13,   14,   14,   11,   12,   11,   12],
    'group'    : ['g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4', 'g5', 'g5', 'g5', 'g5']
})
```

Output_df is what I'm trying to create: replicated rows of the input_df1 per instance of filename in input_df2 with the 'group' value added.

Another question I have is, if I need to filter the rows of each replicated dataframe based on the group type, is it better to do that before joining or after? I was planning on filtering after since I have a better idea of how to do it, but I figure computing on unneeded rows is inefficient when they could be dropped during the replication process. Also I'm dealing with about 30k rows in input_df1 and 800 rows in input_df2 so potential for 24m rows total.
Any direction on which functions I should research to achieve this would be very appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use a join in pandas ? :)

Comment: Well I tried pd.merge(input_df1, input_df2, how='outer', on='filename') but that doesn't replicate the dataframe rows, just adds group column for first instance of each filename.

Comment: you don't use the correct tool from pandas

Comment: I don't really know where to start...

Comment: [rtfm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) :)